# why must I import InvocationTargetException since it's in java.lang?

Tags: java, invocationtargetexception

I'm trying to catch InvocationTargetException in my file, but I get this error if I do not explicitly write the import statement for it.

Since it's under a sub package of java.lang, I don't know why I have to import it.

```
//this is the import statement that worked

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
```

This is the error message:

```
source\DatabaseDemo.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        }catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e ){
                                                                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class InvocationTargetException
  location: class DatabaseDemo
```

Comment: It import java.lang.* by default.But it will not import subpackages IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no concept of sub-packages in Java. We humans view packages as hierarchical for convenience's sake and because source code is typically structured into a hierarchy of directories. However, at a language level no such hierarchy exists. In other words, `java.lang.reflect` is not a "sub-package" of `java.lang`. And since only the classes of the `java.lang` package are auto-imported you have to explicitly import `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: Thank you, so that means you can only have classes at the end of the import statement. Importing * would result in importing all classes under it, not including the package that is under it.

Answer (score 1):

To add on what @Slaw,
There is no implicit subpackage import in java.

```
package a;
class A{}
```

and

```
package a.b;
   class B{}
```

If you want use B in A you have to import it explicitly as : `import a.b.B;` or `import a.b.*;`

Hope that could help

Comment: Thank you so much, that definitely helps